# What is dclsmpedit?

Tags: delphi

What is dclsmpedit package (Embarcadero Editor Script Enhancements)?
Do I need it?

I am not sure what 'Editor Script Enhancements' does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a sample of adding key bindings (your own code editor keyboard assignments), the ability to save keyboard macros (keystrokes recorded for playback), and an edit buffer list to the IDE using the ToolsAPI. You only need it if you want to use it 's functionality. The source is useful if you want to extend the IDE via the parts of the ToolsAPI that they demonstrate. The key binding functionality in `BufferList.pas` implements the `New IDE Classic` key mapping in the IDE itself (as pointed out by @LURD in the comment below).

If you're using Delphi 2007, you can find the source in the Delphi Demos folder (by default on Windows 7 in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ToolsAPI\Edit Keybinding`), and more easily found with the `Start->CodeGear RAD Studio->Samples` menu item. The source for the added functionality is there as well, so you can see what they do and how they are implemented.

In XE3, the source code can be found in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding`, or via `Start->All Programs->Embarcadero RAD Studio XE->Samples`.

Comment: It seems it contains the key mappings for `New IDE Classic`, [New_IDE_Keyboard_Mappings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/New_IDE_Keyboard_Mappings).

Comment: @LURD: It's still a Delphi sample, as evident by the location of the source for it. :-) The  keyboard macros (in `SaveKeyMacro.pas`) are included in that package as well, according to the package .dpk.

Comment: @ken white - 'You only need it if you want to use it 's functionality'. Personally I don't need/use it. But what if other Delphi plugins are using it? I am not sure if other plugins are using it.

Comment: @Altar: It's a key mapping, used by the IDE. If the IDE is not set to use the `New IDE Classic` key mapping, it's not used. Other files that depend on it wouldn't matter, as the IDE key mappings can be changed at any time by the person using the IDE. (D2007 - Tools->Options->Editor Options->Key Mappings). It's also a **demo** in the Demos folder, which means that's exactly what it is - a demo of how to extend the IDE using the ToolsAPI.

Comment: Just as a note: If you're not using that key mapping, the IDE won't load the package containing it, so it shouldn't matter to you whether it's there or not.